# For loop stopping withour error but not completing

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, for-loop

I am trying to convert a xml file to a df using the below code. It currently loops through creating a 4 x 21 df. There are however over a 1000 car parks in the data set, so am expecting a 1000 x 21 df.

```
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd

sites = []

n = 0

with open('CarParkData_1.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = xmltodict.parse(f.read())['CarParkDataImport']

    for carpark in data:
        a = data['CarPark'][n]
        sites.append(a)
        n=n+1


df = pd.DataFrame(sites)
df.shape
```

To get the full data set I am needing to nest for loops, like this;

```
import xmltodict
import pandas as pd

sites = []

n = 0

with open('CarParkData_1.xml', 'r') as f:
    data = xmltodict.parse(f.read())['CarParkDataImport']

    for carpark in data:
        b = data['CarPark'][n]
        sites.append(b)
        n=n+1

        for carpark in data:
            b = data['CarPark'][n]
            sites.append(b)
            n=n+1

            for carpark in data:
                b = data['CarPark'][n]
                sites.append(b)
                n=n+1

                for carpark in data:
                    b = data['CarPark'][n]
                    sites.append(b)
                    n=n+1       

                    for carpark in data:
                        b = data['CarPark'][n]
                        sites.append(b)
                        n=n+1



df = pd.DataFrame(sites)
df.shape
```

The output is now (1364, 21). It does appear that some of the data only has 20 elements not 21 and I wondered if that might be why. Does anyone know why this isn't working or a better way to fix it.

The data is open source uk parking data.

Comment: Could you include a sample of 'CarParkData_1.xml'?

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding how this code would work. You're continuously overwriting variables `b` and `data`

Comment: https://data.gov.uk/dataset/7e7ef556-4173-4dcb-8eef-8ddde4e3824d/car-parks The data set can be found here - its too large to post sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop `for carpark in data:` is iterating over the keys in the `data` dictionary. You should be iterating over all of `data['CarPark']`.

There's no need for a loop, just assign the list:

```
sites = list(data['CarPark'])
```